# create a war file

Tags: java, ant

I want to create a war file for project. The code works fine for creating jar file.
when I run the following ant `build.xml` it still gives the message jar file BUILD SUCCESSFULL.

```
<project name="struts-spring" basedir="../" default="all">
    <!-- Project settings -->
    <property name="project.title" value="Sufalam Struts 2 Tutorials"/>
    <property name="project.jar.file" value="struts-spring.jar"/>

      <path id="class.path">

        <fileset dir="lib">

          <include name="**/*.jar"/>

        </fileset>

        <fileset dir="libext">

          <include name="**/*.jar"/>

        </fileset>

      </path>

        <!-- Classpath for Project -->

        <path id="compile.classpath">

            <pathelement path ="lib/commons-beanutils.jar"/>

            <pathelement path ="lib/commons-digester.jar"/>

            <pathelement path ="lib/struts.jar"/>

            <pathelement path ="libext/servlet-api.jar"/>

            <pathelement path ="libext/catalina-ant.jar"/>

            <pathelement path ="classes"/>

            <pathelement path ="${classpath}"/>

        </path>

        <!-- Check timestamp on files -->

        <target name="prepare">

            <tstamp/>
            <copy
                file="src/struts.xml"
                todir="src/classes"/>


        </target>
        <!-- Copy any resource or configuration files -->

        <target name="resources">

            <copy todir="classes" includeEmptyDirs="no">

                <fileset dir="src/java">

                <patternset>

                    <include name="**/*.conf"/>

                    <include name="**/*.properties"/>

                    <include name="**/*.xml"/>

                </patternset>

                </fileset>

            </copy>

        </target>

        <!-- Normal build of application -->

        <target name="compile" depends="prepare,resources">

            <javac srcdir="src" destdir="classes" 
                         debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source">

                <classpath refid="class.path"/>

            </javac>

            <jar

            jarfile="lib/${project.jar.file}"

            basedir="classes"/>

        </target>
        <!-- Remove classes directory for clean build -->

        <target name="clean"

          description="Prepare for clean build">

          <delete dir="classes"/>

          <mkdir  dir="classes"/>

        </target>

        <!-- Build Javadoc documentation -->

        <target name="javadoc"

         description="Generate JavaDoc API docs">

            <delete dir="./doc/api"/>

            <mkdir dir="./doc/api"/>

            <javadoc sourcepath="./src/java"

                destdir="./doc/api"

                classpath="${servlet.jar}:${jdbc20ext.jar}"

                packagenames="*"

                author="true"

                private="true"

                version="true"

                windowtitle="${project.title} API Documentation"

                doctitle="&lt;h1&gt;${project.title}
                          Documentation (Version ${project.version})&lt;/h1&gt;"

                bottom="Copyright &#169; 2002">

                <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>

            </javadoc>

        </target>

        <!-- Build entire project -->

        <target name="project" depends="clean,prepare,compile"/>

        <!-- Create binary distribution -->

        <target name="dist"

            description="Create binary distribution">

          <mkdir

            dir="${distpath.project}"/>

<!--          <jar

            jarfile="${distpath.project}/${project.distname}.jar"

            basedir="./classes"/>

          <copy

            file="${distpath.project}/${project.distname}.jar"

            todir="${distpath.project}"/>-->



          <war

            basedir="../"

            warfile="${distpath.project}/${project.distname}.war"

            webxml="web.xml"> </war>

            <copy file="${distpath.project}/${project.distname}.war"    todir="${distpath.project}"/>

            <!--<exclude name="${distpath.project}/${project.distname}.war"/>-->

    </target>

    <!-- Build project and create distribution-->
    <target name="all" depends="project"/>
</project>
```

please help me creating a war file.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see you telling the war task what files to put in the war file. You may want to look at the examples [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html).  Ant has fantastic documentation, I think.

Here is an example of using the war task from the link above:

```
<war destfile="myapp.war" webxml="src/metadata/myapp.xml">
  <fileset dir="src/html/myapp"/>
  <fileset dir="src/jsp/myapp"/>
  <lib dir="thirdparty/libs">
    <exclude name="jdbc1.jar"/>
  </lib>
  <classes dir="build/main"/>
  <zipfileset dir="src/graphics/images/gifs"
          prefix="images"/>
</war>
```

Comment: My quite generic build.xml for java webapps is here. It uses dynamic manifest.mf, jar compilation, war packaging and folder strcuture is very streamlined. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18460429/185565